# Creating custom SLDs for Heatmaps using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, heat-map, dynamic

im trying to figure out whether it is possible to create a custom SLD to style heatmaps provided by GeoServer depending on dynamic data input. Already checked out the Rest api and some related documentations, but i did not find a clear answer yet. I am thinking about stuff like a dynamic colour ramp depending on how many features there are to be displayed, also like changing the colours of the table by an input database.

Are there any ways this can be done?

Comment: certainly you can generate SLDs and apply them as external SLD as part of WMS GetMap Request, is there any reason you specify the REST API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the use of

- [Rendering transformation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation). Check the example Heatmap SLD.

with

- [Variable substitution in SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html) to pass dynamic values with WMS request parameters.